# SignalR with orleans how to pass SignalR from startup to grain

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, orleans

I am very new with orleans and trying to grasp everything with grains and so forth.

What i got is that in my startup.cs file i add the SignalR like this

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        Program.WriteConsole("Adding singletons");
        services
            .AddSingleton(achievementManager)
            .AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton(SignalRClient);

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

So far everything is fine i can start my host/application and it connects to SignalR as it should. But what i cant wrap my head around is how do i get this down to my grain? if i had a controller i would simply send it down in the constructor on startup but how do i do this with a grain? Or can i even do it like this. Any guidance is appreciated.

In the grain then i want to do something like this

```
[StatelessWorker]
[Reentrant]
public class NotifierGrain : Grain, INotifierGrain
{
    private HubConnection SignalRClient { get; }

    public NotifierGrain(HubConnection signalRClient)
    {
        SignalRClient = signalRClient;
        SignalRClient.SendAsync(Methods.RegisterService, Constants.ServiceName);
    }

    public Task NotifyClients(object message, MessageType type)
    {

            var registerUserNotification = (RegisterUserNotificationModel)message;
                SignalRClient.SendAsync(Methods.RegisterUserToMultipleGroups, registerUserNotification.UserId, registerUserNotification.InfoIds);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Then i try to call the Notify method from another grain like this

```
var notifier = GrainFactory.GetGrain<INotifierGrain>(Constants.NotifierGrain);
        await notifier.NotifyClients(notification, MessageType.RegisterUser);
```

But trying to do this ends up with an error  like this

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection' while attempting to activate 'User.Implementation.Grains.NotifierGrain'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orleans supports constructor injection, so you can inject the `SignalRClient` into your grain constructor. In your code you are already correctly registering the client using `services.AddSingleton(SignalRClient)`, so I will focus on how to inject the type into your grain.

I do not know what the type the SignalR client object is, but in this example I assume that the type is "`SignalRClient`":

```
[StatelessWorker]
[Reentrant]
public class NotifierGrain : Grain, INotifierGrain
{
    private readonly SignalRClient signalRClient;

    public NotifierGrain(SignalRClient signalRClient)
    {
        this.signalRClient = signalRClient;
    }

    public async Task NotifyClients(object message, MessageType type)
    {
        var registerUserNotification = (RegisterUserNotificationModel)message;
        await this.signalRClient.SendAsync(
            MessageMethods.RegisterUserToMultipleGroups,
            registerUserNotification.UserId,
            registerUserNotification.infoIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this is what i am looking for! if you look at my edit this is how i now try to implement this and SignalRClient is an HubConnection. But when another grain tries to call this like in the edit i get an error i also edtied in. do you know why?

Comment: You're not registering `HubConnection` with the DI container, so you can't inject it. You have to register the client using the same type you want to inject. When you call AddSingleton<T>(T value), you can explicitly specify the type it's registered as (T), so you need to register it as HubConnection. `AddSingleton<HubConnection>(SignalRClient)`

Answer (score 4):

Depends how you're thinking to use SignalR Server, if you're going to host your SignalR server with Microsoft Orleans for sure you need to have backplane to handle the Orleans cluster communications.

You can use [SignalR Orleans](https://github.com/OrleansContrib/SignalR.Orleans/) which has everything done out of the box for you :)

Also if you need a reactive SignalR library for the frontend, you can use [Sketch7 SignalR Client](https://github.com/sketch7/signalr-client)

PS I m one of the authors of both libraries.